# How do I bust this frame buster?

Tags: javascript, css, hide, display, framebusting

There's a Web page with this frame buster:

```css
body {
  display: none;
}
```

```js
if(top != self) {
  top.location = self.location;
} else {
  document.body.style.display = 'block';
}
```

I am trying to bypass this code in order to bust the frame buster. It's easy to make `top.location = self.location` not run, by setting a `sandbox` attribute on the iframe that doesn't include `allow-top-navigation`. However, that leaves the body hidden. How can I overcome that?

Comment: Let's take a step back and first check whether you've remembered to use the [sandbox attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-sandbox)

Comment: @ScottMarcus you misunderstand: that code is in the frame and he can't modify it. He needs to write his own code outside of the frame that bypasses it.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica you are absolutely right